# LookAt matrix when casting shadows parallel to up vector

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am following the [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders) tutorials and have been tinkering with shadows casting. So far everything is working correctly but there is this very specific problem where I can't cast shadows that from a purely vertical directional light. Let's add some code. My light space matrix looks like this:

```cpp
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(-direction, glm::vec3(0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
return glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f) * view;
```

direction is a vector with as direction the direction of the directional light, of course. Everything works well until that direction vector is set to (0,-1,0), because it is parallel to the up vector (0,1,0). To construct the `lookAt` matrix, [*glm*](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) is performing the cross product between the up vector and the difference between the center and the eye (so in that case it's basically the direction), but that cross product won't give any result since the two vectors are parallel.

Knowing all of this, my question would be : how should my `lookAt` view matrix when the up vector and the direction of the light are parallel ?

Edit : Thank you for your answer, I changed my code to this :

```
if(abs(direction.x) < FLT_EPSILON && abs(direction.z) < FLT_EPSILON) 
view = glm::lookAt(-direction, glm::vec3(0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); 
else 
view = glm::lookAt(-direction, glm::vec3(0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)); 
return glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f) * view;
```

and now everything works fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the up-vector and the line of sight are parallel, then the view matrix is undefined, because the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) is (0, 0, 0).
The view matrix is an [Orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), this means each of the 3 axis is perpendicular to plane which is formed by the 2 other axis. Respectively the angele between the axis is 90°.
The view matrix is the inverse matrix of that matrix which defines the viewing position and orientation. This matrix is defined by the parameters to [`glm::lookAt`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#gaa64aa951a0e99136bba9008d2b59c78e). 2 of the axis a res specified by the line of sight and the up-vector. The 3rd axis is calculated by the cross product.

This all means, you have to specify the matrix by 2 [Orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality) directions. If the angle between the direction vectors is not exactly (90°) then this is corrected by `glm::lookAt`. But the algorithm fails to do that if the vectors are parallel. 
Define a line of sight (direction) vector and a up-vector, with an angle of 90° to each another. If you rotate on of them, then you've to rotate the other vector in the same way.

e.g. Lets assume you've a direction vector (line of sight) and an up-vector:

```non
direction: (0, 0, 1)
up       : (0, 1, 0)
```

If the direction vector is rotated by 90° then the up-vector has to be rotated by 90°, too:

```
direction: (0, -1, 0)
up       : (0,  0, 1)
```

Comment: If the line-of-sight cannot be parallel to the up vector, then how do they achieve the top-down look in 3D editing software, especially when the user is orbiting the camera around (like in Blender etc.)? Or are they ignoring the problem completely with the hope that the user will never trigger the exact parallel line-of-sight due to random differences in floating point numbers?

Comment: @JustAMartin 1. Who are "they"? 2. The up vector is always perpendicular to the line of sight. Therefore, the up vector must be rotated with the line of sight.

Comment: "They" - the software developers. But thanks for the explanation, my confusion was caused by being lazy and assuming it's enough to always keep the up vector as (0,1,0) for the system where Y is the up direction. It seemed to work just fine until I tried looking straight down. I was not aware that I have to recalculate the up-vector for lookAt every time the line-of-sight is rotated.